# ng-if or ng-show stops array push to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-show

I have an Angular address book. It has a list of names and titles on one side and a full bio on the other. One feature of the bio is that you can make someone the main contact. Checking that box highlights it in the list. I am doing this by updating the contact object with a boolean and then using, at first, an ng-if but now I'm trying to use an ng-show. It works except that if I try to add a new contact it'll be added to the contacts array but not show up in the list. This is due to some sort of conflict with how I'm using the ng-if/ng-show. I tried adding an $apply() into the mix but it didn't work correctly. I'm wondering if anyone has ever run into this or has a better solution.

This is the repeater:

```
    <div class="contactsDetails">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 contactList">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy: 'name' | filter: query" ng-click="viewContact(contact)">
                <td ng-show="contact.mainContact === true" style="font-weight: bold; background: aliceblue">{{contact.name}}</td>
                <td ng-show="contact.mainContact === true" style="font-weight: bold; background: aliceblue">{{contact.title}}</td>

                <td ng-show="contact.mainContact === false">{{contact.name}}</td>
                <td ng-show="contact.mainContact === false">{{contact.title}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This is a sample contact object:

```
                    {
                    name: "John Doe",
                    title: "Lawyer",
                    company: "Corona",
                    email: "john.doe@corona.com",
                    phone: "123-456-7890",
                    address: "1234 Market Street, Anytown, MA, 02143",
                    mainContact: false
                    }
```

I tried to cut down on how much code I'm showing in here but if anyone wants me to post more or actually create a codepen I can do so.

Comment: I think it is better to use ng-class for that case

Comment: Yeah I thought about ng-class too but I'm not sure how to implement it with a contact.mainContact === active expression. It chokes on the period.

Comment: how do you filter your search result? | filter: query

Comment: ng-class="{'some-class': contact.mainContact}"

Comment: @erolkaya84 using this: 

    <input type="text" class="form-control contactSearch" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="query">

Answer (score 0):

All praise to E. Abrakov. Ng-Class is the best solution. Thanks.